# Group file to New Folder?

Tags: file-io, vbscript, batch-file, batch-processing

I have to copy files, make a new folder and then paste those files into the new folder so often.

I wonder if we can make a batch file or vbscript file to perform this task? Just select the files and choose "Group to New Folder" from the context menu. That'll be awesome!

Comment: Btw, I've found a solution in .NET 4.0 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution in .NET 4.0

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is write an HTA application.  You could have a selection listbox that could be auto-populated with the current folders files when you first launch the hta.  Then just have a simple button than will prompt you for a folder path/name to create when selected and a simple sub to just move the selected files over, maybe through results to the screen or something.  Obviously with error trapping and all that's a little bit much code to just paste in here, but it should be pretty easy to do.

If you're looking for help getting started with the hta interface, I recommend you check out the ["HTA Helpomatic"](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=231D8143-F21B-4707-B583-AE7B9152E6D9&displaylang=en) which you can use to get the basic GUI, as well as selection box code.  Obviously you can write the script subs to do the real work.